# Why are the orbits of elements of Lie algebra under adjoint action of the Lie group even dimension manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I can't find a proof of this statement anywhere - in fact I can't even find a statement of this statement anywhere. My advisor told me this in our last meeting, but I am having trouble verifying it. I know that they are manifolds, but I cannot figure out the even dimension part.

Comment: I suggest you read the first section in [Nilpotent Orbits in Semisimple Lie Algebras](https://books.google.de/books?id=9qdwgNmjLEMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Collingwood and McGovern. There, they explain this result for reductive lie algebras, but without giving full proofs. The basic idea is to show that adjoint orbits can be identified with coadjoint orbits, which carry a natural structure of a symplectic manifold (and hence have to be even dimensional).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is only true for semisimple Lie groups. I will assume the orbits are manifolds, since you know this already.

Fix some $x$ and consider the orbit map $G \to \mathfrak{g}$ given by $g \mapsto \mathrm{Ad}(g) x$. Its derivative is the map $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}$ given by $y \mapsto \mathrm{ad}(y) x$; this is simply the map $-\mathrm{ad}(x)$ and we only need to know the dimension of its image which is $\mathrm{dim}\, \mathfrak{g} - \mathrm{dim}\, \mathrm{ker}\, \mathrm{ad}(x)$ and $\mathrm{ker} \, \mathrm{ad}(x)$ is just the centralizer of $x$, denoted $Z(x)$.

Consider the following counterexample: Let $\mathfrak{n}$ be the strictly upper triangular $3 \times 3$ matrices and let $x$ be a generic element, so that $x^3=0$ but $x^2$ is not zero. It follows that the vector space of all matrices commuting with $x$ is just given by polynomials in $x$; of these the matrices in $\mathfrak{n}$ are given by the span of $\{x,x^2\}$. Hence $\mathrm{dim} \, Z(x) = 2$, while $\mathrm{dim}\,\mathfrak{n}=3$, so the orbit is $1$-dimensional.

The result does hold for semi-simple Lie algebras though: assume now $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple and let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a Cartan subalgebra containing $x$.

---

EDIT: as Claudius mentions, this assumption is erroneous because $x$ may not be semisimple. If we do assume $x$ is semisimple we can see why its orbit is even-dimensional, as I explain at the end of the post. If we can do a similar analysis for nilpotent elements, we should be able to prove the result, because every element $x$ admits a Jordan-Chevalley decomposition into unique semisimple and nilpotent parts $x=s+n$ and $Z(x)=Z(s) \cap Z(n)$ since $s$ and $n$ are polynomials in $x$. However computing the dimension of $Z(n)$ seems to be a little more difficult.

---

Now, assuming $x$ is semisimple we get the root space decomposition
$$ \mathfrak{g} =\mathfrak{g}_0 \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha} \mathfrak{g}_\alpha $$
and 
$$ Z(x) = \mathfrak{g}_0 \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \, | \, x \in \ker \alpha} \mathfrak{g_\alpha}$$ 
where the sum is over all roots $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(x)=0$. The point is that if $\alpha(x)=0$, we also have $(-\alpha)(x)=0$. Since every root space is one-dimensional, its clear that the dimension of every centralizer $Z(x)$ has the same parity, including the zero vector whose centralizer is all of $\mathfrak{g}$. Taking a look at the formula above, we see that the dimension of the image is always even.

Comment: If you fix a Cartan subalgebra containing $x$, don't you implicitly assume that $x$ is semisimple?

Comment: Oops, you're right, that's an important oversight. We might be able to get around that by studying the semisimple part of $x$ though.

Comment: I would be curious to see such an approach. But I am not knowledgeable enough to see how this could work.